# Unable to get a textbox' default value to populate from a query

Tags: ms-access-2000

I have a form field that I'm trying to populate from a query named qryCreditsUsed. The query is listed below and works as expected. The result should the number of billing records associated with a given authorization number. The result can, but does not need to be saved as it should be dynamic.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS credits
FROM [tbl BILLING]
WHERE ((([tbl BILLING].AUTHORIZATION)=[Forms]![frmAUTHORIZATION]![AUTHORIZATION]));
```

SPECIFIC: I'm trying to populate a form field (textbox) via the textbox's "Default Value" property using "=DLookUp("[credits]","qryCreditsUsed")" w/o any success. The field is blank. The "Control Source" for the field is "balance" field from the "authorization" table.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!!**

The textbox was bound to the "balance" field. I changed the control source to "=DLookUp("[credits]","qryCreditsUsed")" (same as "Default Value") and now it works.